# Different connecting rod designs for diesel vs gasoline engines?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, pistons

I've noticed that diesel engines tend to have rod caps that are installed at an angle as supposed to straight on gasoline engines.

[This](https://fandjexports.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Volvo-D6A-Connecting-Rod.jpg) is an example of a generic diesel engine piston and [this](https://media.gettyimages.com/id/182456025/sv/foto/rod-piston.jpg?s=612x612&w=gi&k=20&c=ODT6Fhp8MTlNnzs70Yp5Pm0x5kB_k40o1Uy2vGP4g1g=) is an example of a generic gasoline engine piston. Notice how connecting rod caps are kind of slanted on the diesel piston compared to the gasoline, is there any advantage to that mechanically or does it just make it easier to install the piston?

Comment: Why don't you use the site properly?

Answer (score 1):

#### It's for clearance.

Getting the longer conrod/piston into the longer stroke cylinder and past the camshaft is the reason.

Comment: I don't quite get it, are you saying that the connecting rod wouldn't physically fit through the cylinder if it wasn't slanted like that?

Comment: it's for assembly/maintenance